# Looking for Animated Celtic Japanese Movie around 2010

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for an animated movie that felt like a mix of 'classic' Scottish and Japanese stories. Unfortunately, I don't remember anything about the plot, other than it having to do something with a dragon.

This movie was on Netflix around 2010-2011. I distinctly remember it being on Netflix at the same time as both "Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time" and "The Last Airbender" (Live action movie)

The only scene I remember is a knight in armor running on a bridge with a trail of smoke, and when he got off the bridge, he died and collapsed on the ground in dust and ash.

EDIT: I'm not entirely sure, but I think it was 3D CGI Animation.

Comment: A little too busy to submit this as a possible answer, but- is it maybe Secret of Kells?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--3AvyeMhmU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A French production, but the vibe is Scottish with high fantasy influence, the CGI movie **Dragon Hunters (2009)** has a ten second scene involving a knight who races across a drawbridge, staggers inside, then falls apart into ashes and empty armour.

[image]

The scene in question occurs at 6:58 on the version of the movie found on Youtube.

The basic plot is that the titular Dragon Hunters are hired to go and slay a world-devouring dragon after certain omens foretell the dragon's return.  One such omen is the 'Smouldering Knights'

Comment: This seems very likely

Answer (score 3):

Could this be "[Record of Lodoss War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_of_Lodoss_War#Anime)"? It has a decidedly Celtic look and feel to it, despite being classically Japanese anime.

There are also dragons, knights and all manner of dust effects

Answer (score 0):

Dante's Inferno (2010)
OR
Tales from Earthsea (2006)

Comment: Tales from Earthsea was my first thought when I read this

Comment: Could you add a description about these two candidates; it helps the author decide whether or not your propositions are what they are searching for