# Animated movie or TV series including floating islands and ships

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remembered a TV series or movie that I watched when I was a kid. It was on DVD, I think. It was animated, and the color scheme was bright. I watched it around 2002-2010.

All I remember is that there are floating islands and ships, and I think there was a war or something. I can remember one scene where there was a ship that crashed on an island in the winter. Another scene that I remember is where a few characters were on an island (some kind of a main island/city), and they were in the library looking at a map.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see if there is anything else you can edit in? For example, when did you watch this?  What were the predominant colors of the animation? Every little bit of information helps to identify your story.

Comment: Maybe Last Exile?

Comment: Its not Last Exile. Its animated but not as anime, like cartoon or something. Im really bad at explaining but ty tho

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104841/looking-for-animated-celtic-japanese-movie-around-2010 ?

Answer (score 8):

It could be [*Dragon Hunters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Hunters) (originally "Chasseurs de dragons" in French). It aired in 2006.

Two guys hunt dragons for money in a funny fantasy world, flying from floating island to floating island. Each new episode was a new contract for a dragon. They were all very different.

Their flying vehicle crashed on a snowy floating island during the 8th episode of the first season, fitting to your memory. [You can find this episode here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5qf85y). The crash happens at 04:00 (it's in french, but a US version exists)

[image: Image of the show showing a blue creature sat on a boy's head who is sat on the back of a large man wielding a sword]

[A movie adaptation](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/chasseurs_de_dragons_dragon_hunters_die_drachenjager?) has been realized in 2008. Same universe, but in 3D animation.

[Trailer here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFQmAZ23i1s) and movie poster below:

[image: movie poster showing the main characters, those mentioned in the image above and also a young girl]

Comment: Its its close but  its not Dragon Hunter

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [*Dragon Flyz*](http://dragonflyz.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Flyz_Wiki) (Dragon Flyz Les Guerriers Volants)?
It was a French cartoon where mankind must live in floating cities that were protected by a group of dragon-riding warriors against an evil lord.

[image: A golden city floating with a large sphere in the center and tall sky scrapers on either side]
<sub>*The floating city.*</sub>

[image: The protagonist: a muscled man wearing blue with white highlights on the back of a dragon-like creature]
<sub>*The protagonist.*</sub>

[image: The antagonist: a red demon like creature with a red massive dragon stood behind him]
<sub>*The antagonist.*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[Skyland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland)*? As TVTropes put "Totally not inspired by *The Last Exile*". "Totally not inspired by" is a Blatant Lie.

It was a cel-shaded CGI series, aired a single season in 2005-2007.

[image: Skyland poster showing the main protagonists on the left side: white coated older gentlemen, a teen boy and a young girl and the antagonists on the right side: a muscled person covered head to tor and two bald people (a man and a woman) in a black uniform]

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of [*Aero-Troopers: The Nemeclous Crusade*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382521/), a 2003 CGI movie including floating islands, a giant mechanical whale, and kids training to be soldiers.

> In a world of floating islands, young Joshua is orphaned after a monstrous creature destroys his home. Picked up by the airship Nemeclous, he joins her crew in their quest to hunt down and slay the beast.

[image: Aero-Troopers poster showing the mechanical whale with lots of large sharp teeth, a floating airship, and the main characters a woman and man (part of the crew), a steampunk robot and the young boy]

Comment: I've edited this to include some more information (an IMDb link, the synopsis from that and a poster) to help jog the OP's memory to see if this is correct. If you want to remove any of my changes or make some of your own you can [edit] your own post to do so.